# CSS: center a menu

Tags: html, css, navigation

How do I center this menu in css? I have tried left: 50% or text-align: center but nothing works. Do you guys have any idea?

I have to add more details but that was actually it, so I have to write rubbish now.
I have to add more details but that was actually it, so I have to write rubbish now.
I have to add more details but that was actually it, so I have to write rubbish now.
I have to add more details but that was actually it, so I have to write rubbish now.
I have to add more details but that was actually it, so I have to write rubbish now.
I have to add more details but that was actually it, so I have to write rubbish now.
I have to add more details but that was actually it, so I have to write rubbish now.

Thanks in advance

CSS:

```
#navigation {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(navigation.jpg);
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align:center;
}

#navigation ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}

#navigation li {
    float: left;
    border: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

#navigation a {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
    background: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    border: none;
}

#navigation a:hover, #navigation #current a {
    background: url(button.jpg);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your html as well. That would be really useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your content in a container, set a `width` and use `margin:auto`

**EDIT**

Ok this is a bit of a mess, is there a reason you are absolute positioning the header? Your `ul` does not need `position: relative` and your `li`'s should be using `display:inline-block` instead of `float`.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7vc4u/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
#navigation ul {margin:0 auto;}
```

on your #navigation ul element?

Comment: yeah, but I actually only want the #navigation ul to be centered. The #navigation is just a bar with a full width

Comment: Have just edited my answer, agreed that posting your HTML would be useful

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
#navigation {
   text-align:center;
}
#navigation ul {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `#navigation` element has `width:100%;` so that block level element takes the entire screen. You can try to center it's children with `text-align: center;`.

Try settings a specific `width` on your `#navigation ul` and then apply `margin: 0 auto; text-align:center;`.

Depending on what you're going for, it may be better to do `#navigation li{ display: inline-block;}` instead of `float: left`